# Tableau Heat Map With Date Range

Tags: tableau-api

I have 3 fields on a table.

```
USER_ID 
TIME_IN 
TIME_OUT
```

When using the Tableau out-of-the-box heat map, I believe it's only picking up the exact TIME_IN / TIME_OUT times. How do I make it so the heat-map will pick up the full time range (room utilization) for each record?

Comment: Tableau KB: https://kb.tableau.com/articles/howto/showing-records-that-fall-within-a-period-of-time

Comment: Hey Devlin when I try to add the calculated field with "DATEADD('week',(INDEX() - 1),[Start Date])" I get the error: "cannot mix aggregate and non-aggregate arguments with this function"

Comment: There's a [KB article](https://kb.tableau.com/articles/issue/error-cannot-mix-aggregate-and-non-aggregate-arguments-with-this-function-when-creating-a-calculated-field) for that too!  And a [thread in the community forum](https://community.tableau.com/thread/141161) that may give you a pointer as to why this is happening with a date field.

Comment: Thank you for the articles, Devlin. I've managed to get a graph of my own up, but the active sessions readings are a bit off. I did have to change the 'weeks' to 'hours' as I need it broken down by the hour. Could this be causing it?